# Convert cell array of numbers to matrix (cell2mat) while converting empties to zeros

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a function that uses `strfind` in a `cellfun` call to find which string items in a cell array match a specified string. For example:

```
cellfun( @(x) strfind( x , 'openmask'), fileNames, 'uniformoutput', false)
```

The original cell matrix is like this:

```
fileNames = {'sub11att-openmask.txt', 'sub13det-masking', ...};
```

The result for this looks like this:

```
[10]    []    [10]    []    [9]    []
```

I am trying to find a function that will convert this to:

```
10  0  10  0  9  0
```

Using `cell2mat` I get:

```
10  10  9
```

So I have to use this currently:

```
x(cellfun('isempty', x))={0};
cell2mat(x);
```

Is there a function that is cleaner than this (i.e. a one-liner solution)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are empty cells always at regular intervals?

Comment: @SardarUsama no they aren't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works even if there are several occurrences of the sought string. It finds the first such occurrence if there's any, or gives `0` otherwise:

```
result = cellfun(@(x) sum(min(strfind(x, 'openmask'))), fileNames);
```

The code uses `min` to keep the first occurrence. This will give either a number or `[]`. Then `sum` transforms `[]` into `0`.

If you prefer to keep the last occurrence,  change `min` to `max` or use [Sardar Usama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698672/sardar-usama)'s suggestion:

```
result = cellfun(@(x) max([0 strfind(x, 'openmask')]), fileNames);
```

Comment: An idea to get rid of the `sum` function:  `result = cellfun(@(x) max([0 strfind(x, 'openmask')]), fileNames)`

Comment: Very fancy handiwork @LuisMendo. Thanks for this. By the way, what's the best way to organise one's library of user-defined functions, for access by any MATLAB script I write? I'd like to start a collection of functions like this that are handy that I need to use a bunch for various things. Thanks!

Comment: @teepee Hm I'm not sure, I just keep one or two folders with all of them. You could always include a line in your [`startup` file](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) to [add the path](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) to those folders. Glad you found the answer useful!

Comment: @Sardar Actually your suggestion works for several matches and produces the last one. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a new variable `y`:

```
y(~cellfun('isempty', x)) = cell2mat(x);
```

It will break if a cell has more than one element tough.